# Is it true that entropy estimation is meaningless if samples are not i.i.d.?

Tags: self-study, estimators, entropy, information-theory

Let $X$ be a discrete-support stochastic variable. Information entropy is a number defined as
$$H(X)=-\sum_{n} p\left(x_{n}\right) \log p\left(x_{n}\right) \geq 0$$
Let $\hat{H}$ be an estimation of $H$. Is it true that $\hat{H}$ is meaningless if $x_{n}$ are not i.i.d.?
Could a random walk be used as a source?

Comment: What do you mean by "$x_n$ are not i.i.d"? In this context, $x_n$ are not samples from a distribution, they are the range of $X$.

Comment: @mhdadk: I mean that, if $\hat{H}$ can be defined in terms of frequencies (i.e., counts) $f\left(x_{n}\right)$ which go to replace $p\left(x_{n}\right)$ in $H(X)$, then $\hat{H}$ is meaningless if $x_{n}$ are not i.i.d..

Comment: Could you be more specific in your question about what $\hat{H}$ is? It could be $$\hat{H} = -\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \log{p(x_i)},$$ but there is no way to tell.

Comment: Actually, I have a time series I would like to estimate Shannon's entropy about. I wonder if  this series should be considered a realization of an i.i.d. process to obtain a proper entropy's estimation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems that you are dealing with a random process/signal instead of a single random variable. Let this random signal be
$$
\mathbf{X} = \{X_1,X_2,...,X_N\}
$$
such that the set of possible values of $\mathbf{X}$ is $\mathbb{R}^N$. Since each of $X_1,X_2,...,X_N$ are continuous, then we are interested in the [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) of $\mathbf{X}$, otherwise known as the **joint differential entropy** of $X_1,X_2,...,X_N$. This is defined as
$$
h(\mathbf{X}) = h(X_1,X_2,...,X_N) = -\int_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^N} p(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \log{p(\mathbf{x})} \ \text{d}\mathbf{x}
$$
So, how well you estimate $h(\mathbf{X})$ depends heavily on how well you estimate the joint probability density function $p(\mathbf{x})$. The i.i.d assumption that you mention might be made to make it easier to estimate $p(\mathbf{x})$, but it may not necessarily be true.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_estimation) offers a more detailed discussion of entropy estimation methods.

Answer (score 1):

you probably refer to the asymptotic equipartition property?
[AEP Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_equipartition_property) $X_1,...,X_n$ have to be iid then, since $-\frac{1}{n}\log p(X_1,...,X_n)=-\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\log p(X_i)\rightarrow -E[\log p(X)] $ in probability, which is $H(X)$